# How to reverse the place of Element to a Text with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Hi everyone i am just wondering if we can change or reverse the place of an element to a text with javascript or jquery for example we have:

```
<h2 class='title'>Travel <span class='top-title'>Latest From</span></h2>
```

We want to make it like this :

```
<h2 class='title'><span class='top-title'>Latest From</span> Travel</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, just prepend the span, and it's moved in the DOM

```
$('.title').prepend($('.top-title'));
```

or the other way around

```
$('.top-title').prependTo('.title');
```

If you have more than one of these, you'd probably want to do

```
$('.title').prepend(function() {
    return $('.top-title', this);
});
```

Where you just prepend the one `.top-title` inside each `.title` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can swap the childnodes:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].childNodes;
  elements[1].parentNode.insertBefore(elements[1], elements[0]);
}
```

```html
<h2 class='title'>Travel <span class='top-title'>Latest From</span></h2>
```